# Display appended comments on hover

Tags: sharepoint-online, append-changes

We have a Sharepoint list that we are going to use as a project tracker.  We have a Comments Column that has version history on and append comments on.  As of now, the comments column shows 'View Entries' and we have to click on 'View Entries' to show the comment history.

We want to make it where we can hover over 'View Entries' and the comments display on hover.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, there is no out-of-the-box method to achieve hover over 'View Entries' and display the comments in SharePoint online.

The **'View Entries'** is suitable for **multi-line text column**, we can view all the content by clicking on 'View Entries'.

[image]

[image]